# How to add more sliders than 1 slider to home page?

Tags: html, design, code, slider

We currently have 1 slider on our home page. We want to add another in a new area. Is there a plugin/app that will allow us ? or is just just a case of copying the HTML code ?

This is  a big topic for us as we have having difficulty with it.

Any feedback and help would be great thank you.

Comment: Could you specify this in a bit more detail please?

Comment: you can use magestore banner slider.its free.
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/banner-slider-14.html

Comment: @Klettseb  I made a graphical example to explain more. We want to add sliders into the block where we have images displayed. Image: http://i.imgur.com/irB8AHP.jpg

Answer (score 0):

There are lot 3rd party plugin/extension at [magento Extension MarketPlace](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?id=&s=7&pl=0&eb=0&hp=0&q=banner&t=0&p=1) .By Installing them,you can use multiple banner for home.

You need use those may this resolve,your issue.